# Angular subscribe to a service not working

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I can't understand why, can anybody please explain:

when I do this it woks:

```js
initOptions(){
    
      this.ruleService.findRules().subscribe(
        res => {
          this.rules =res;
          this.rules.forEach(r => {
            this.optionsSelect.push({label: r.name, value: r.id});
          });
         console.log(this.optionsSelect);
        }
      );
     
  }
```

but when I don't use the variable **this.rules** the log shows the data but the template goes blank (white component (just the component not all the page) )
**Note that:** the html is a made table (a bunch of <tr> <td>) and this code is needed to fill a drop down list data.

```js
initOptions(){
    
      this.ruleService.findRules().subscribe(
        res => {
          //this.rules =res;
          res.forEach(r => {
            this.optionsSelect.push({label: r.name, value: r.id});
          });
          console.log(this.optionsSelect);
        }
      );
      
     
  }
```

Comment: can you reproduce the issue inside stackblitz

Comment: It's better to see your html but I can guess that you don't use `ChangeDetectorRef` and `detectChanges()` method to update your view once you got your data.

Comment: I'm guessing that angular doesn't detect the changes because optionsSelect is a reference that is not modified. You should try `this.optionsSelect = res.map(r => ({label: r.name, value: r.id}));`

Comment: See Loscos answer. The first case "works" because you push a new reference on a component field `this.rules` which triggers a detection cycle. If you remove that assignment, there is no reason for angular because you do not change the reference of  `this.optionsSelect`.
Both solutions described in the previous comments should work.
If optionsSelect already has values inside you want to keep, use
`this.optionsSelect = {...this.optionsSelect, res.map(r => ({label: r.name, value: r.id}));`